# SQL Query using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

> Write a query that displays the student firstname, lastname, course number, and course name
>   for all students taking classes – use an INNER Join. Label the output columns Student First, Student Last,
>   Course Number, and Course Name. You should have 7 rows.

is the question in my lab.

there are three tables students,courses,registration

I can get the names of the students that are registered in a course with

```
select firstname,lastname from students
inner join on registration students.studentid=registration.studentid
```

but when i try to get the other data the teacher wants returned from the courses table it doesnt work I tried a million things but what makes sense to me is

```
select firstname,lastname,coursenumber,coursename from students,courses
inner join registration on students.studentid=registration.studentid
```

but it gives me an error unknown column students.studentid in on clause.

Comment: what are the columns in students?

Comment: Also how are you joining the table `courses`?

Comment: is this right: ` join on registration students.studentid=registration.student.id`  I think you have typos, can you correct these?

Comment: FYI, You're not using a join to connect the courses table

Comment: sorry forgot to add that columns in students are studentid,firstname,lastname,major,admitdate,graddate,gender,dob

Comment: @dsquaredtech We need to know the columns in `courses`

Comment: columns in registration studentid,courseid                        and colums in courses courseid,coursename

Comment: you will also need to describe the relationship between students and courses like students.studentid = courses.studentid in the where cluase or on a join clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, missing the joining condition between `registration` and `courses`. You have an odd mix of implicit and explicit `INNER JOIN`s.  Your join into `courses` should be another `INNER JOIN` which is joined through `registration` to `students`.

```
SELECT
  firstname, /* <-- don't forget to label your columns as required */
  lastname,
  coursenumber,
  coursename 
FROM
  students
  /* `students` map into courses via many-to-many relation in `registration` */
  INNER JOIN registration on students.studentid = registration.studentid
  /* Inner join through `registration` into `courses` */
  INNER JOIN courses ON registration.courseid = courses.courseid
```

And don't forget your column aliases to satisfy the column output naming requirements. Use the `AS` keyword in your `SELECT` list. I'll leave that part of the assignment for you to solve.

> Label the output columns Student First, Student Last, Course Number, and Course Name

Comment: this gives me an error unknown column 'courses.courseid' in 'on clause'

Comment: @dsquaredtech Not possible unless you misspelled it _or_ you used a table alias like `INNER JOIN courses AS c ON...`

Comment: In your comment above, you said the cols in courses were _colums in courses courseid,coursename_  You did not mention a `coursenumber` column as in your `SELECT` list though..

Comment: aha i'm an idiot that's probably it it's not courseid it's coursenumber

Comment: @dsquaredtech as both `registration.coursenumber` and `courses.coursenumber`? Substitute the correct column names in the join's `ON` clause and you should be in business.

Answer (score 0):

```
select firstname,lastname,coursenumber,coursename from students
inner join registration on students.studentid=registration.studentid
JOIN courses  ON courses.courseid = registration.courseid
```

You mentioned `courses` in your query but you didn't `join` it to anything.

Comment: I keep trying these queries and get an error similiar to what I was getting with select firstname,lastname,coursenumber,coursename from students,courses
inner join registration on students.studentid=registration.studentid except now the unknown column is courses.courseid in the on clause

Comment: Glad your question got answered and congrats on joining S/O! In the future, if you have any more MySQL related questions, what would help would be to run `SHOW CREATE TABLE _tablename_` for each table involved in your queries.